FIlter Fuction alternative to creating a list in Excel
I currently have this formula using the Filter Function, but I need it to work on order versions of Excel.
is there an alternative way of getting the same result?

I've tried using the Index function, but I just can't seem to get it right.

For the Record, next time you ask a question, please include the test data as a markdown table and the formula as text so we can copy paste.

Use INDEX(AGGREGATE())
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$16)/(($B$2:$B$16=$E2)*($C$2:$C$16=$F2)),ROW($ZZ1))),"")

This will require you to put the formula in the first output cell and then drag it down at least the max number of rows that will be returned by any combination.
